# My three column responsive layout is not respecting flex order

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make a three columns layout for my website using flexboxes.

However, my 'commentCaMarche' div does not seem to follow the flex order, it is located at the top of the 'details-index' column. Do you know how to solve this problem?

```css
#credits {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #FB3D00;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#details-index {
    font-size: 1.6vmin;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
    order: 1;
    display: flex; /*Note : Each of my columns is also a flex container for other contents I omitted*/
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

(...)

#commentCaMarche {
    font-size: 2vmin;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
    order: 2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

(...)

#sources {
    font-size: 1.4vmin;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
    order: 3;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div id='credits'>
    <div id='columns'>
        <div id='commentCaMarche'>
            <h2>Comment ça marche</h2> (...)
        </div>
        <div id='details-index'>
            <h2>Le détail</h2> (...)
        </div>
        <div id='sources'>
            <h2>Sources des données</h2> (...)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So where should the `commentCaMarche` be? ... It looks exactly how you told it to, if referring to the `order`

Comment: By the way, including `(...)` in your CSS is not necessary (and obviously not valid CSS) to show that you have other styles there. If the styles are relevant to your problem, they should be in the MCVE. If they're irrelevant, then there's no need to even allude to them.

Comment: It would be great if you could accept an answer, if any, that solve your question, or let us know what is missing, so we can find one that does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css for making it responsive 3 column

```
#columns{width:100%; float:left;}
#commentCaMarche{width:33.33%; float:left}
#details-index{width:33.33%; float:left}
#sources{width:33.33%; float:left}
```

Comment: Just as simple as that? Thank you, it works perfectly!

Comment: @TomFévrier Well, that is not `flexbox` and you'll get disappointed when try to achive equal height etc. which won't work with floats ... and floats is a really bad way to do layout

Answer (score 0):

You need to change order property for your flex columns. [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxyu53x2/)

```
#details-index {
    font-size: 1.6vmin;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
    order: 2;
    display: flex; /*Note : Each of my columns is also a flex container for other contents I omitted*/
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#commentCaMarche {
    font-size: 2vmin;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
    order: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `flex-wrap: wrap` will make your columns break line when they doesn't fit the width available, so by removing it from the `columns` rule, you'll have 3 proper columns at any width.

*I also temporarily removed the `order` from the flex items, so they show up in the same order they are placed in the markup, but if you need to change them like in your sample, please add it back, or why not simply swap them in the markup*

```css
#credits {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #FB3D00;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#columns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#details-index {
  font-size: 1.6vmin;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#commentCaMarche {
  font-size: 2vmin;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#sources {
  font-size: 1.4vmin;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div id='credits'>
  <div id='columns'>
    <div id='commentCaMarche'>
      <h2>Comment ça marche</h2>
      (...)
    </div>
    <div id='details-index'>
      <h2>Le détail</h2>
      (...)
    </div>
    <div id='sources'>
      <h2>Sources des données</h2>
      (...)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```